# The distributivity formula of sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

In "Mathematical Foundations of the Calculus of Probability" by Jacques Neveu, it has the following formula
\begin{equation*}
    \bigcup_{j \in J} \bigcap_{i \in I_{j}} F_{i}^{j} = \bigcap_{\{i_{j}\} \in K} \bigcup_{j \in J} F_{i_{j}}^{j}
\end{equation*}
where $K = \prod_{j \in J} I_{j}$, i.e., the set of all sequences $\{i_{j}, j \in J\}$.

However, I could not see why it is true.

- The LHS means its element $x$ is in at least one group $I_{j}$ of $\{F_{i_{j}}^{j}\}$ indexed by the bigger set $I_{J}$.
- The RHS seems to be bigger than the LHS, it states that for
  every sequence $(i_{j})$, there always exists a $j_{0}$th term in the sequence such that $x \in F_{i_{j_{0}}}$.

Can anyone give me some intuitive why this formular is right? I tend to believe LHS $\subset$ RHS, but why does RHS $\subset$ LHS. Help appreciated.

P.S., the superscript $j$ of $F$ is redundant in my opinion. Please correct me if I am wrong.

**Appendix**:

Following the reformulation of @mihaild, I have a better understanding about the RHS. And I can clearly see LHS $\subset$ RHS, however, for the other way around, I cannot clearly see it.

The negation of LHS: $x \notin$ LHS $\Leftrightarrow$ $\forall j \in J$, $\exists i \in I_{j}$ such that $x \notin F_{i_{j}}^{j}$

The negation of RHS: $x \notin$ RHS $\Leftrightarrow$ $\exists f:J \to \bigcup_{j}I_{j}$, $\forall j \in J$, $x \notin F_{f(j)}^{j}$.

Following the answer provided below, there exists a $f$ that makes $x \notin$ RHS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's slightly simpler to think about $K$ as set of functions from $J$ to $\bigcup\limits_{j \in J} I_j$ s.t. $f(j) \in I_j$.

$x$ is in the left part if for some $j_0$ it is in $F_i^j$ for every $i$ (1).

$x$ is in the right part if for any function $f$, there is some $j$ s.t. $x$ is in $F_{f(j)}^j$ (2).

(1) implies (2): take the $j_0$ from (1), and then for any function $f$, $x$ will be in $F_{f(j_0)}^{j_0}$, as it is in $F_i^{j_0}$ for any $i$, in particular for $i = f(j_0)$.

Not-(1) implies not-(2) (assuming axiom of choice): if (1) is false, then for any $j$ there is $i \in I_j$ s.t. $x \notin F_i^j$. Say that $f(j)$ is equal to this $i$ (here you need choice), and you get $f$ for which there is no $j$ s.t. $x$ is in $F_{f(j)}^j$.

Comment: Thanks for your time. (2) has no requirement in $j$, that is, for every function $f$,  the corresponding $j$ can be different. However, (1) seems to require that $j_{0}$ should be the same among functions $f$

Comment: (2) also requires $j_0$ to be the same: if we can for every $j$ choose a function that doesn't work for this $j$, we can choose a function that doesn't work for any $j$.

Comment: Still cannot get it. From your 3rd paragraph(which I think is right), I cannot see any need that $j$ should be the same

Comment: For the 2nd paragraph, I think it is not for every $i$ but every $i \in I_{j_{0}}$

Comment: In your last paragraph, "then for any $j$ there is $i$ s.t. $x \notin F_{i}^{j}$" should be changed to "then for any $j$ there is $i \in I_{j}$ s.t. $x \notin F_{i_{j}}^{j}$, and I cannot see such a construction of $f$ implies not-(2)

Comment: We have shown that there is $f$ s.t. for any $j$, $x$ is not in $F_{f(j)^j$, this is exactly negation of (2).

Comment: Now I re-edited your statement, and tend to think you are right, can you have time to check my edited note?

Comment: Seems good to me. I understood a better way to show the other way aroubd: let $K' = \prod_j \{x \in I_j | x \notin F_{I_j}^j\}$. Then negation of (1) is exactly each term in the product to be non-empty, axiom of choice says that $K'$ is not empty, and taking $f \in K'$ in the right part gives us that $x$ is not in the intersection.